# How can I improve this one to many ActiveRecord data model?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a home-grown (not my own) versioning system with the following data structure:

```
  create_table "activities", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "source"
    t.datetime "created_at",       :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       :null => false
    t.integer  "head_revision_id"
  end

  add_index "activities", ["head_revision_id"], :name => "index_activities_on_head_revision_id"
  add_index "activities", ["source"], :name => "index_activities_on_source"

  create_table "activity_revisions", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "activity_id"
    t.string   "activity_type"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.integer  "modified_by_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                      :null => false
  end

  add_index "activity_revisions", ["activity_id"], :name => "index_activity_revisions_on_activity_id"
  add_index "activity_revisions", ["activity_type"], :name => "index_activity_revisions_on_activity_type"
  add_index "activity_revisions", ["title"], :name => "index_activity_revisions_on_title"
```

The application displays a list of activities from newest to oldest, paginated (will_paginate) 20 to a page. This is the query used to generate the list:

```
Activity.where(conditions)
        .joins(:head_revision)
        .includes(:head_revision)
        .order('activities.id DESC')
```

The `conditions` vary according the values passed from a search form. For the initial list display, `conditions` is blank.

On the surface, this query is simple enough but in execution, it is horribly slow with large data sets. We currently have about 102,000 activity records and 512,000 activity_revision records. On our production server, the query takes nearly 2 seconds to provide a count. In a development environment, it is abysmal.

I feel that there is something inherently wrong with the data model and I'm hoping someone can show me a better way.

EDIT: Explain run on the basic query without conditions:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM `activities`  INNER JOIN `activity_revisions` ON `activity_revisions`.`id` = `activities`.`head_revision_id`;
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------+--------+-------+
| id | select_type | table              | type   | possible_keys                        | key     | key_len | ref                                        | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | activities         | ALL    | index_activities_on_head_revision_id | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                       | 106590 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | activity_revisions | eq_ref | PRIMARY                              | PRIMARY | 4       | cms_production.activities.head_revision_id |      1 |       |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and on the count(*) query:

```
mysql> explain SELECT count(*) FROM `activities`  INNER JOIN `activity_revisions` ON `activity_revisions`.`id` = `activities`.`head_revision_id`;
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+--------+-------------     +
| id | select_type | table              | type   | possible_keys                        | key                                  | key_len | ref                                        | rows   | Extra            |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+--------+-------------     +
|  1 | SIMPLE      | activities         | index  | index_activities_on_head_revision_id | index_activities_on_head_revision_id | 5       | NULL                                       | 106590 | Using index      |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | activity_revisions | eq_ref | PRIMARY                              | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cms_production.activities.head_revision_id |      1 | Using index      |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+--------+-------------     +
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: UPDATE: Although I still feel that the data model is inherently bad, I have determined the reason for the large timing discrepancy between live and development was due to a poorly tuned development percona. Setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size=7GB` greatly improved query performance.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are indexing several columns already which is good. I would say one of the best ways you can ensure your queries are as efficient as possible is to make sure **ALL of the `conditions` that deal with querying/retrieval in the db, have their corresponding columns indexed**.

Comment: The searches are going to be somewhat slow just because most use LIKE. It's the COUNT query that sucks up most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing why a query is slow is no fun, fortunately we shouldn't have to.

Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain and let's see what your `Activity` queries are actually doing.

It sounds like you're querying a mysql database so take a look at the `key` in that those explain results. As MilesStanfield suggested, it sounds like you'll see that you are not using an index effectively.

Comment: I've added a couple of EXPLAIN's above.